# MongoDB shardCollection command in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to shard a collection using mgo library in Go.
Looks like I can't figure out to run commands using Session.Run call.
Here is my code:

```
if err := session.DB("admin").Run(bson.D{{"shardCollection", "visits.visits-2016-05"}, {"uuid", "1"}}, &result); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

I've tried several variants of passing key parameter, but I'm always getting `no shard key` error

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that you have to specify that the second field is the key of `key` and the value is the subdocument of `{uuid: 1}`. This way you're matching the exact fields listed by the mongo documentation: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shardCollection/.

The code I'm using for the same process is:

```
if err := adminDb.Run(
            bson.D{
                {
                    "shardCollection",
                    "logs.log_"+dateString,
                },
                {
                    "key",
                    bson.M{
                        "sk": "hashed",
                    },
                },
            }, &result); err != nil {
                log.Println("Failed to shardCollection logs.log_"+dateString, err)
            }
```

So you might want to try

```
if err := session.DB("admin").Run(bson.D{{"shardCollection", "visits.visits-2016-05"}, {"key", bson.M{"uuid", "1"}}}, &result); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for - couldn't figure out how to pass a subdocument.Also, in my case the correct "key" field would be {"uuid", "hashed"} like in your example.